# Equivalent for Dutch commode?

Tags: meaning, translation

In Holland we use *commode* to indicate a dressing table or lowboy specifically for changing diapers and dressing a baby:

[image: commode]

The commode is usually ditched after the babies have grown out the diapers. I can't imagine this piece of furniture being absent in the English speaking world but when I look on ebay, Etsy and others for commodes, lowboys, or chest of drawers I don't find anything related to changing baby diapers.

What would be good translation for the Dutch word *commode*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here in the States those are generally referred to as [*changing tables*](http://www.toysrus.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=2256272).

"Commode" to us means "toilet".

Comment: Or just 'change table'

Comment: Thanks. This is an answer to my question. Actually I need to describe "a cloth over the changing tables", which would be "a cloth over the changing table" as "changing tablecloth" could easily be misunderstood?

Comment: @drjerry: Does the cloth hang suspended over the table, or does it lie upon the surface of the table? "a cloth over the changing table" suggests the first (to me, amyway) but "a cloth on the changing table" suggests the second.

Comment: It's actually suspended over the table, so first meaning.

Comment: @drjerry - In the US, a cloth on the changing table would commonly be called a "changing pad" or "diaper pad".    "Changing tablecloth" is an unfamiliar term, but I could guess what you meant from its literal meaning.

Comment: @drjerry do you mean a "Changing mat"?